# How to split the given String String s="agshshdhdbdhsusjdidjdjdjfjfjrywoetdmfhd" ;

Tags: java, string, selenium, indexing, split

My string is
`String s="agshshdhdbdhsusjdidjdjdjfjfjrywoetdmfhd";`
we have to split it into multiple substrings by

Split from `0-4`, `5-8`, `9-12` and so on...

Comment: How about `substring()`?

Comment: Please send your code

Comment: From js: `s.match(/.{1,4}/g)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code.
Hope it helps.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s= "agshshdhdbdhsusjdidjdjdjfjfjrywoetdmfhd";
        List<String> list = splitIntoEqualPartition(s, 4);
        for (String a: list) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

    public static List<String> splitIntoEqualPartition(String str, int partitionSize) {
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<String> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
        while (str.length() >= partitionSize) {
                partitions.add(str.substring(0, partitionSize));
                str = str.substring(partitionSize);
        }

        if (str.length() > 0) {
            partitions.add(str);
        }
        return partitions;
    }
```

Comment: whats the purpose of if(Str == null){ return null;} even its working fine without it too - thanks dude

Comment: you  will get a nullpointerexception if its null.